# Where can I find the whitelist for downloading images in The Bat! email client?

Tags: email, whitelist, the-bat

As the title states I'm lost and can't find the whitelist where I allowed certain url's to be allowed to download images in EMails. Where's the whitelist located?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem on their site: https://www.ritlabs.com/en/support/help/69/#6628